# Making Widgets Disappear in a Frame

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root= Tk()
root.title('Select State')
framey=Frame(root)
d_type = tk.StringVar()
d_type.set('1')
d1 = Radiobutton(root,  variable=d_type, text="Texas", value="Texas",command=lambda: cities(root))
d1.pack()
d2 = Radiobutton(root, variable=d_type, text="NJ", value="NJ",command=lambda: cities(root))
d2.pack()
def cities(root):
    texas= "Texas"
    nj ="NJ"
    state = d_type.get()
    if state== texas:
            f_band = tk.StringVar()
            f_band.set('Dallas')
            f1 = Radiobutton(framey,  variable=f_band, text="Dallas", value="Dallas")
            f1.pack()
            f2 = Radiobutton(framey,  variable=f_band, text="Houston", value="Houston")
            f2.pack()
    if state== nj:
            f_band = tk.StringVar()
            f_band.set('Newark')
            f1 = Radiobutton(framey,  variable=f_band, text="Newark", value="Newark")
            f1.pack()
            f2 = Radiobutton(framey,  variable= f_band, text="Princeton", value="Princeton")
            f2.pack()
    framey.pack()
```

I need help figuring out how to make a widget disappear. Basically when a state is pressed, city options pop up. However- I want such options to disappear if another state is selected. Right now when Texas is pressed Houston/Dallas pops up, but still stays on the screen if NJ is selected. How do I destroy the city options from appearing if another state is selected?

Comment: You can first delete all children of `framey`, then create the required radiobuttons.

Comment: @acw1668 should I do it after each if statement?

Comment: No, before if statements.

Comment: @ClaudiaBesse The answer given by JohnT will solve your issue. If you don't understand that then I also have an answer that can solve your issue without changing much from your code. I haven't posted it yet because John T has posted the answer which also solves other problems in your code. Like in your code sometimes the `Radiobutton` blinks, etc. And the solution which I have will only solve the issue you have stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also take your state/city out of an if-else and just go with the button calling a function for each state, its easier to add states this way (at least in my mind its easier). At the start of each state callback, I have the frame clear called. you could also use pack_forget() in the clear function. I'm not sure of a benefit toward either one, but I typically use destroy() because its shorter, and it doesn't require knowing if things were grid()ed or pack()ed, and I normally forget the '_' in pack/grid_forget().

```
from tkinter import *

def clearF(fr):
    frame = fr
    for item in frame.winfo_children():
        item.destroy()
        #item.pack_forget()
        #either destroy 

def citiesTX():
    clearF(framey)
    f_band.set('Dallas')
    f1 = Radiobutton(framey,  variable=f_band, text="Dallas", value="Dallas")
    f1.pack()
    f2 = Radiobutton(framey,  variable=f_band, text="Houston", value="Houston")
    f2.pack()

def citiesNJ():
    clearF(framey)
    f_band.set('Newark')
    f1 = Radiobutton(framey,  variable=f_band, text="Newark", value="Newark")
    f1.pack()
    f2 = Radiobutton(framey,  variable= f_band, text="Princeton", value="Princeton")
    f2.pack()

root= Tk()
root.title('Select State')
framey=Frame(root)
d_type = StringVar()
f_band = StringVar()
d_type.set('0')
d1 = Radiobutton(root,  variable=d_type, text="Texas", value="Texas", 
                 command= citiesTX)
d1.pack()
d2 = Radiobutton(root, variable=d_type, text="NJ", value="NJ", 
                 command= citiesNJ)
d2.pack()
framey.pack()

root.mainloop()
```